# Host not found in upstream nginx

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to add a website to my Nginx configuration like so:

```
upstream radio {
    server localhost:3006;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    
    server_name radio.website.com;

    location / {
         proxy_pass http://radio;
    }
}
```

On `localhost:3006` there is a `meteor.js` application running. I can visit it by using the IP address of my server and the appropriate port. It works (but I want my clients to be able to access my app by using my website's domain name, through Nginx.)

The problem is that Nginx will not boot. It fails with the `host not found` error if I try restarting it with `service nginx restart`.

> [emerg] host not found in upstream "radio" in
> /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:37

I have several other server blocks defined in a very similar way and syntax in my configuration file and I have no idea why this one is failing.

I tried replacing `http://radio` with `http://localhost:3006` in the config file, which gets rid of the error (Nginx successfully restarts), but then I can't run `certbot` ("could not find a matching server block for radio.website.com Set the 'server_name' directive to use the Nginx installer"), nor can I display the site in my browser (I get a certification error, or a blank page even).

It seems that Nginx is failing to resolve "radio" although it is defined in the config file.

Any idea on what I might be doing wrong here?

Thank you for your insights.

Comment: Missed a trailing `;` in `proxy_pass http://radio` ?

Comment: thank you for your answer! unfortunately it's only a typo in my question, but not in my config file (i'm editing my question).

Comment: Your question is off-topic in StackOverflow. You have a better chance to get it answered if you move it to [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) or to [Superuser](https://superuser.com).

Comment: thank you, i'm also checking [Server fault](https://serverfault.com).

Answer (score 0):

I deployed my app to an other server with the exact same configuration and it's now working. Not sure what went wrong here, but at least my site is now up and running. thank you!